# Failing Perc6i or Backplane?

Tags: windows, dell

I have a Dell R710.

6 drive config.

(2) drives are RAID 1, (4) drives are RAID 5

Recently, on the RAID 5 side, one drive (#2) showed predictive failure LED sequence. I ordered a new drive and before it arrived then #4 started showing predictive failure. THEN #3 showed predictive failure.

I replaced #2 but now it almost immediately goes into failed mode and does not rebuild.

#3 and #4 still show predictive failure but online.

#5 is normal.

The system is still online but not sure for how long. The system is a Vmware ESXi system host so no "window" utilities to use.

I am not sure if the core of the problem is the PERC6i card or backplane is the one failing? I have a spare 6i but not a Backplane.

To be honest I have not ever encountered a failing PERC or backplane before.

Thoughts on which once is the true culprit?

If it could be the PERC, I know it is not just swap of the PERC procedure. I believe if memory serves me, it will detect a foreign adapter. Do I import the foreign config? Is that pulling the setup from the drives?

To make matters worse the customer is now telling me he does not have a backup.

So PERC or Backplane?
Advice on Perc replacement procedure?

Answer (score 1):

The PERC boards have a battery that often fails, usually after about five years of use, and this can cause the effect you are seeing. This can also happen if your disks are mismatched for a number of reasons. You should be able to install and use the Dell diagnostic tools (`omconfig`, etc) and MegaCLI to detect any issues. The PERC will also probably warn in `dmesg` and certainly will show problems in POST on boot. I would also strongly recommend a backup as soon as possible as there is the potential for loss of data. You are correct about importing foreign configs and this may fix the issue but it can also wipe the array depending on the state of the system. I inherited a couple of hundred Poweredge machines and this is a regular problem.